# How can I clear my MongoDB collection between Mocha tests? Collection.remove({}) isn't working. . .

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mocha.js

How can I clear my MongoDB collection between Mocha tests? Collection.remove({}) isn't working. . . .

Does anyone see what I could be doing wrong?

I've tried `User.remove({})` with this syntax, as well, to no avail.

Also, if you have a moment, does this seem like a reasonable way to write this test? I'm admittedly new to testing.

```
const User = require('../../../app/models/user');
const config = require('../../../config/config');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiAsPromise = require('chai-as-promised');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const expect = chai.expect;
chai.use(chaiAsPromise);
mongoose.connect(config.database, { useMongoClient: true });
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

describe('The user model', () => {
  describe('during creation', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      // Clear the User collection of all users.
      User.remove({}, () => {});
    });
    afterEach(() => {
      // Clear the User collection of all users.
      User.remove({}, () => {});
    });

    it('should store the user in the database', () => {
      let userData = {
        email:    'blah@user.com',
        password: '1234'
      };
      let user = new User(userData);

      return user.save().then(
        newUser => {
          return User.findOne({_id: newUser._id}, (error,retrievedUser) => {
            let expected = newUser._id;
            let actual = retrievedUser._id;

            console.log(actual,expected);
            return expect(actual).to.equal(expected);
          });
        }
      );
    });
```

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The solution to that person's problem does not work in my situation.

Comment: Collection.drop()

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `deleteMany`.

Depending on the case, you may want to empty the database *beforeAll* and *afterAll* specs rather that *beforeEach* and *afterEach* spec.

Also, ensure that you're using a testing database and not testing with a production or development database.

```
User.deleteMany({}, (err) => console.log(err));
```

Comment: This didn't work either. I'm still getting duplicate key errors.

Comment: What is happening in `config/config`?

Comment: It feeds `  'database':   process.env.DATABASE_URL || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/blah',` into `mongoose.connect`.